# Как одновременно удалить несколько локальных бранчей в git

Tags: git

Подскажите, как грохнуть одновременно все локальные бранчи с префиксом `prj_name_`

```
$ git branch
  ...
* prj_name
  prj_name_camera
  prj_name_defs
  ...
```

Пробую

```
v.malov$ git branch -D prj_name_*
error: branch 'prj_name_*' not found.
```

Comment: я бы наверно выводил названия веток, скопировал в sublime text, Ctrl+A, Ctrl+L и привел в последовательность названий в строке. Если эта не разовая задачка а для скрипта то не пойдет

Answer (score 5, accepted):

где то так

```
for b in $(git branch | egrep "^prj_name_"); do git branch -D $b; done
```

только перед началом проверьте список бранчей на удаление

```
git branch | egrep "^prj_name_"
```

и если что, скорректируйте регулярку.

Answer (score 1):

Прежде всего, нужно переключиться на какую-то ветку, которую вы не будете удалять. Git не позволит удалить выбранную в данный момент ветку.

Подумайте, хотите ли вы удалять ветки, которые никуда не замержили? Так можно потерять несохранённые изменения. Если не хотите, то переключитесь на ту ветку, в которую должны быть замержены результаты и используйте `--merged`:

```
git checkout prj_name
git branch --merged | egrep "^\s*prj_name_"
```

Это список веток, которые будут удалены. В регулярке `^\s*` обозначает начало строки и сколько-то пробельных символов. Начало строки отсеивает все случаи, где `prj_name` - не префикс, а середина строки. `\s*`необходимо, т.к. команда `git branch` выводит два пробела перед названиями всех веток кроме текущей (перед ней будет `*<пробел>`)

Если результат проверки верный, можно удалять.

```
git branch --merged | egrep "^\s*prj_name_" | xargs git branch -d
```

Если вы хотите удалить в том числе незамерженные ветки, то:

```
git branch | egrep "^\s*prj_name_" | xargs git branch -D
```